# html textbox not working in SVG foreignObject

Tags: html, angularjs, svg

I'm working on a flowchart web application using Angular-JS and svg:

[flowchart website](http://silverlight4web.com/flowchart%5Csample1%5CAngularJS-FlowChart-master%5CAngularJS-FlowChart-master)

everything works fine but there is an strange problem: HTML elements used in SVG (which are in fact rendered inside the foreignObject tag) don't work. For instance text box cannot be edited at all and combo box items cannot be selected. Click on the title (نام برگه), it will then be changed into a textbox, but you cannot write anything in this textbox, what is going wrong?

here is my foreignObject tag code:

```
<foreignObject x="50" y="50" width="350" height="200" style="z-

index:2000;" >

<script>
    var nodeIndex = 0;

    function Switch(index) {
        var name = "div" + index;
        div1.style.display = "none";
        div2.style.display = "none";
        div3.style.display = "none";

        tab1.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
        tab2.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
        tab3.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";

        document.getElementById(name).style.display = "";
        name = "tab" + index;
        document.getElementById(name).style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    }

    function Collapse() {
        if (imgCollapse.src.indexOf("visible.png")!=-1) {
            imgCollapse.src = "flowchart/collapsed.png";
            divBody.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            imgCollapse.src = "flowchart/visible.png";
            divBody.style.display = "";
        }
    }

    function ChangeTitleLabel(id) {
        var lbl = document.getElementById(id);
        var txt = document.getElementById(id.replace("lbl", "txt"));
        lbl.style.display = "none";
        txt.style.display = "";
        txt.value = lbl.innerHTML;
    }

    function ChangeTitleText(id) {
        var txt = document.getElementById(id);
        var lbl = document.getElementById(id.replace("txt", "lbl"));
        lbl.style.display = "";
        txt.style.display = "none";
        lbl.innerHTML = txt.value;
    }

    Init();
    function Init() {

        var titlebars = document.getElementsByClassName("titlebar");
        nodeIndex = titlebars.length;
        var tmpTitleBar = document.getElementById('divTitleBar');
        tmpTitleBar.id = "divTitleBar" + nodeIndex;
        var iconid = "imgIcon" + nodeIndex;
        var lbltileid = "lblTitle" + nodeIndex;
        var txttiteid = "txtTitle" + nodeIndex;

        document.getElementById("divTitleBar" + nodeIndex).innerHTML += "<span id='" + lbltileid + "' style='cursor:hand; cursor:pointer;' onclick='ChangeTitleLabel(this.id)' >نام برگه</span>";
        document.getElementById("divTitleBar" + nodeIndex).innerHTML += "<input id='" + txttiteid + "' value='نام برگه' type='text' style='display:none; z-index:2000; font-family:Tahoma;' onclick='ChangeTitleText(this.id)'  />";

        document.getElementById("divTitleBar" + nodeIndex).innerHTML += "<img src='flowchart/icon.png' style='cursor:hand; cursor:pointer; height:22px; float:left;' id='" + iconid + "' />";
    }

</script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" /> 
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
            <div style="width:350px;   direction:rtl; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:small;">
                <div style="width:350px; height:22px; background-color:lightgreen;  direction:rtl; border-style:solid; border-color:black; border-width:1px;" class="titlebar" id="divTitleBar">
                    <img src="flowchart/visible.png" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer; height:22px;" id="imgCollapse" onclick="Collapse()" />


                    </div>
<div style="width:350px; height:200px; font-family:Tahoma; direction:rtl; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;" id="divBody">
</div>
                </div>
        </body>
    </foreignObject>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

- Init()

  You call your `Init` routine before the dom has been created. Instead of calling it inside the `script` section, register an onload handler with the *svg* element (not contained in your code):

  Note that `onload` must be all-lowercase and that the handler cannot be registered with the `body` element inside the `foreignObject` ( which has been the error in the previous version of this answer).
- script tag

  The `script` tag needs to be pulled out of the `foreignObject` and inserted as a child of the `svg` element.
- function Collapse

  You do not define the variable `divBody`.
  Change the function `Collapse` to:

  function Collapse() {
      var divBody = document.getElementById('divBody');
      //...
  }
- function ChangeTitleLabel/Text

You use the event handlers incorrectly. Specify their call by

```
onclick='ChangeTitleLabel(\""+lbltileid+"\")'
onclick='ChangeTitleText(\""+txttiteid+"\")'
```

(You are generating the lexicalisation of the call inside a string)

- meta

  You do not need the `meta` element.

Comment: unfortunately onload="init" doesn't work here (why?), I've even tested static textboxes (i.e. I had inserted text box elements in the HTML rather that adding them dynamically using JS) but again with no luck. I think there is a problem related to SVG and foreignObject

Comment: I rather it isn't - I've just tested your code  inside a standard svg wrapper on chrome 40 and it works fine. Have you looked into possible error messages in the javascript console ?

Comment: take our code, wrap it with a standard svg element,save it as a .svg file in your local filesystem, call that file in the browser. Btw, just noticed that i didn't test thoroughly enough, no errors reported but doesn't work anyway.

Comment: I've corrected my answer. The initialization demonstrably works now.